# Android what is the difference between Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal and Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am confused between two styles. I am using api level 24 as a minimum sdk version for my android app. So what is the difference between those two styles of progressbar? Can I directly use Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal since my minimum sdk version is api 24? Like:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/t_progressbar1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Note: I am using material design themes for my app. Which style is preferable or correct one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal` internally uses  `Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal` only if you see the code.

As you mentioned you are using material design and your min sdk is 24 I think you should use `Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more query can I use this style if my progressbar is in RemoteView?

Comment: I myself didn't try ever, but as we know RemoteViews have support for Progressbar so can assume that we can use the style, but please do try it once.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews

Comment: Just one more help, I want to customize that style in styles.xml Hence I am defining it in styles.xml like:     <style name="MyCustomPBStyle" parent="Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal"></style> But android studio says cannot resolve symbol Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal. So how to correctly define it in styles.xml?

Comment: <style name="MyCustomPBStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>